# SSRS Expand Tablix to fill page

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create an invoice with ssrs and I can not figure out how to get the tablix to expand to the bottom of the page.  I have all the page breaks working correctly, but if there are only a couple of line items, there is white space between the bottom of the tablix and the footer.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, just had to sleep on it.

I had to remove whitespace by changing ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace to true, then create a rectangle and place the tablix inside the table.  Make the rectange the size need to fill the page.

Thanks,